# Pretty Test Multiple Variables against Nil value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

Is there any pretty way to test the below? I have multiple `parameters` which I need to know if any one of them is `nil`

This is what I am using now, I am sure there is an efficient way to test all and type `nil` once but not sure how:

```
if title == nil || name == nil  || height == nil || productName == nil {
            //Do something
        }
```

I am using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) and at they moment, they don't support error handling, hence, my `init()` `throws` errors and I need to check if the values from `Map` are nil or not and through if they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a simple extension on CollectionType to check for a collection of Optional value, if at least one element is not nil, if all elements have value or if none have value.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == Optional<AnyObject>, Index.Distance == Int  {

    func allNotNil() -> Bool {
       return !allNil()
    }

    func atleastOneNotNil() -> Bool {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }.count > 0
    }

    func allNil() -> Bool {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }.count == 0
    }
}


var title: String? = ""
var name: String? = ""
var height: Float? = 1
var productName: String? = ""

[title, name, height, productName].allNotNil()
[title, name, height, productName].atleastOneNotNil()
[title, name, height, productName].allNil()
```

In your case, you could use it like this,

```
 if [title, name, height, productName].atLeastOneNotNil() {

  }
```

Or, you could discard the extension above and simply use it like this,

```
 if [title, name, height, productName].flatMap { $0 }.count > 0 {

 }
```

**For Swift 4,**

```
extension Collection where Element == Optional<Any> {

    func allNotNil() -> Bool {
        return !allNil()
    }

    func atleastOneNotNil() -> Bool {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }.count > 0
    }

    func allNil() -> Bool {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }.count == 0
    }
}
```

**Updates for Swift 5,**

Few new functions have been added to `CollectionType` such as `first(where:)` and `allSatisfy(where:)` and it is used here.

extension Collection where Element == Optional {

```
func allNil() -> Bool {
    return allSatisfy { $0 == nil }
}

func anyNil() -> Bool {
    return first { $0 == nil } != nil
}

func allNotNil() -> Bool {
    return !allNil()
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great option!

Comment: I am testing the .allNotNill() but keep getting false although all are not nil. I want to test to see if at least one is nil, which to use?

Comment: You should use atLeastOneNotNil as it is or in your case. The allNotNil() version works fine with me.

Comment: Thanks - I added func atleastOneIsNil() -> Bool {
        return self.contains { $0 == nil }
    }

Comment: You can speed up `atleastOneNotNil` by doing a for loop and just return false if you encounter any nil during the loop. The flatMap will run the entire loop. You don't have to run the entire loop if you encounter a nil. This can help with very large arrays.

Comment: Looks like allNotNil must be `return self.flatMap { $0 }.count == self.count`, not `return self.flatMap { $0 }.count > self.count`. How flat array can have more elements than original one (except situation with nested arrays)?

Comment: @StanislavChernischuk Please see my edits. I also added methods on `Collection` for Swift 5.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short version using a collection literal:

```
let isAnyNil = ([title, name, height, productName, nil] as [Optional<Any>]).contains { $0 == nil }
```

It's similar to @GeneratorOfOne's `flatMap` and `count` variant. I prefer the simplicity of `contains`.

If you do this often, I'd go with a free function to avoid the need to specify the type:

```
func isAnyNil(optionals: Optional<Any> ...) -> Bool {
    return optionals.contains { $0 == nil }
}

isAnyNil(title, name, height, productName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to know, but if it is kind of unwrapping than it better to do so in Swift 2.0

```
if let email = emailField?.text, password = passwordField?.text {
    //here you have both email & password
 }
```

if you enter a method and need to do something in case any of them is nil, I would recommend using a `guard`:

```
guard let email = emailField?.text else {
    // It is nil, do something
    return
}
// if we got here, we have 'email' and it is not nil.
```

**Side Note:**

I'm guessing when you mean `efficient` you really talk about `pretty` or `easy` and not really efficient, because in either cases you would have to evaluate all arguments to see if they are nil.

If indeed you just want it to be pretty, you could use .filter to check

```
var nilElements = [email,password].filter{0 == nil}
```

you will get back only the elements which are `nil`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. I have a multiple if-statement that test multiple values if one of them is nil. Now I am sure there is an option like if name, title, height == nil or if name || title || height == nil.

Comment: @TalZion please see me side note.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not pretty enough as I would need to create an array just to test if either one is nil.

Comment: @TalZion as far as I'm concerned, there is not such thing as you require in Swift.